# Elixir DynamicSupervisor get child by name

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

In the `DynamicSupervisor` module we have a function called `start_child` which registers a child and starts it. My question is: how later on i can find that particular child by name, because for example the `Process.whereis` function takes only atom as parameter and I dont want to name children processes with atom, I name them as tuples for example

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [Registry module and the :via tuple](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Registry.html#module-using-in-via)

In the example above you can replace `Agent` with your child module.

```
{:ok, _} = Registry.start_link(keys: :unique, name: Registry.ViaTest)
name = {:via, Registry, {Registry.ViaTest, "my_child_name"}}
{:ok, _} = Agent.start_link(fn -> 0 end, name: name)
Agent.get(name, & &1)
#=> 0
Agent.update(name, &(&1 + 1))
Agent.get(name, & &1)
#=> 1

Registry.lookup(Registry.ViaTest, "my_child_name")
#=> [{self(), nil}]
```

This example uses a string as key (`"my_child_name"`) but it can be any elixir term like a tuple.

Comment: What is the reason of copy-pasting Elixir documentation here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic solution AFAIK. You have two options to manage this.

If all the children of you `DynamicSupervisor` are different modules, use [`DynamicSupervisor.which_children/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DynamicSupervisor.html#which_children/1) to list children and pattern match the last parameter against the module name.

Otherwise, you should name your children using [`:via`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html#module-name-registration) tuple and maintain your own alternative registry to lookup children.